# Gradle: How to check for duplicate dependencies in project?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I am attempting to remove all *out-of-date / unnecessary* `dependencies` from my project.

When looking at the output of the `allDeps` task I can see that there are several dependencies that are replicated but the output is difficult to understand.

Is there a specific Gradle `tool / task` that I can use to get a clearer view of what dependencies I can remove?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `./gradlew projectName:dependencies` to see a tree of all the dependencies of your project. Both that are repeated or with different versions are remarked in the different configurations and classpaths.

Comment: Thanks, do I need the wrapper to do this?

Comment: No, you can run it without wrapper as well.

Comment: Ok, Can I get the tree to print to a text file?

Comment: My application is actually a multi-project build, do I need to repeat this for every project within it, or is there a way to display the tree for the full application?

Comment: Yes, you need  to run the command for every project. To print it concat the output to a file like: `gradle project:dependencies >> output.txt`

Comment: What is the advantage of running this over the "alldeps" task

Comment: To be honest I am not sure which task is it. This is not one from gradle, maybe you have it declared somewhere. The official task created by gradle is `dependencies`. Probably you or a plugin you are using declares the allDeps for you extending the task `DependencyReportTask`

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING:** Unfortunately, the plugin fails to add its tasks to the gradle build for me using gradle 3.3. It still fails for gradle 4.3.1 (thanks to MoePad for reporting).
The project seems to be not very active, so it might not work as expected.

---

For completeness: There is a **gradle plugin available** called [dependency-checker](https://github.com/cjstehno/dependency-checker) which does "assist in validating project dependencies". Additional link to the [gradle plugin page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.stehno.gradle.dependency-checker).

*One of the tasks added is:*

> **CheckDependencies**
>
> A Task used to validate that the build has *no duplicate dependencies* -
>   a dependency with the same group and name, but with a different
>   version. The build will be failed if any duplications are found.

It may help identifying duplicates/outdated dependencies as well.

Adding the plugin to your gradle build file:

```
plugins {
  id "com.stehno.gradle.dependency-checker" version "0.2.2"
}
```

This should add the following gradle tasks:

- checkDependencies
- checkAvailability

For details about configuration and what the tasks exactly do, please refer to the [github page](https://github.com/cjstehno/dependency-checker).

Comment: @MoePad so instead of looking at the date and exactly what I've written and then adding a helpful comment to improve the answer you're downvoting it because it did not help you? I think this is not what downvoting is for. Projects can be outdated but my answer is not wrong per se!

Comment: No need to get personal or make any assumption about my motivation. Your answer wasn't working at the time you posted it (to quote directly from yourself "Unfortunately, ATM the plugin fails"). Neither do you provide any information how this plugin could work (e.g. a compatible gradle version).

Comment: Also I'm sorry for the short comment yesterday. You're right that I should have given more information about what you can improve. Which I hope I did. I always appreciate contribution on stackoverflow but want to avoid others in this case to investigate this answer. I hope my motivation is clear now :)

Comment: @MoePad I'm sorry if I've been offensive in any way. It has not been intentional. The project is still active according to the last commit being about a month ago, so I assume it works with the latest gradle version, yet I cannot go through all answers all the time to update them. I've added my eperience with gradle 3.3 where it did not work as a warning. The links provide the basic introduction how to add it. If it is not working, it is probably the best to create an issue in github and hope that the author responds.

Comment: @MoePad I've tried to clarify my answer, I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I would write the warning at the beginning (and would also add that this plugin is failing for gradle 4.3.1 as well). Anyway, I removed the downvote to close this issue for both of us!